# How to quickly create an empty file of a specified size in rust

Tags: rust

I want to create an empty file with a size of 1GB without initializing the contents of the file. Is there a way to quickly create a file of a specified size like in golang?

golang code：

```golang
func CreateFileBySize(file string, size int64) error {
    f, err := os.Create(file)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer f.Close()

    if err := f.Truncate(size); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

Truncate changes the size of the file. It does not change the I/O offset.
Is there an existing similar method in rust

Comment: You could use libc provided functions like pwrite or fallocate

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but a file of size other than zero cannot, by definition, be empty. It may contain all zero bytes, but it is not empty.

Comment: @RichardNeumann I assumed they were talking about [sparse files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file). These would take only an inode entry, and possibly a storage block or two (I don't know whether 0-data sparse files are a thing or whether the file needs actual data in one of the extremity blocks).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as i know there is no support for sparse files in the Rust standard library (assuming that's what you mean, I have no idea if it is).

According to https://www.systutorials.com/handling-sparse-files-on-linux/ and https://users.rust-lang.org/t/rust-create-sparse-file/57276/2 you can just `seek` forward and write a single byte, and you'll get a sparse file.

Alternatively, you can use the `libc` crate and call [`fallocate(2)`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html) and / or [`pwrite(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/pwrite) depending on your requirements